# Multilanguage site performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, multilingual

I'm currently working on a site (ASP MVC) that support Multilanguage where every web content is stored in Database, for example I have english version, spanish version, etc. But I'm worried about the performance when it goes to production because everytime a user hit my page, there are at least 20 database calls to get the content.

Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient?

What I can't do is :

- Merge all database call into 1 call on every page load (this takes
  too much effort).
- Make a separate html page for every language (I need the end user to be able to add new language without me changing the code hence the
  database design).

I was thinking about caching everything in user's browser and compare it everytime they hit my page and it will only call the database if it doesn't match but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Comment: You should look for a cache system that save the static parts of your pages

Comment: you said, `when it goes to production because everytime a user hit my page, there are at least 20 database calls to get the content.`. i want to know, wheather or not if system is multilingual, there are always atleast 20 calls?

Comment: @Zeeshan: hello, thanks for the response, the answer is 'no', I need a lot of database call because I need to get the text based on the language chosen by user. If it's not multilanguage, I could just put every text in the html pages.

Comment: well, why don't you then just create resource files (according to languages) and set some culture information variable, and the resource will be rendered accordingly. got my point? do you have idea about resource files?

Comment: As suggested you should just cache all the lcoalization strings you have. For example when your app start you can retrieve all localizations into a static dictionary or server cache and request the information from there

Comment: @Zeeshan: No I'm not, do you have any good tutorial I can read? So I should just load every localizations from database on app_start and put it in resource files(some kind of static dictionary?) and load the request from there everytime user hit my page instead of calling database. Am I right?

Comment: Resources is a different concept of storing localiztions, so if you have them in your DB then resources won't suite you at all. If you want to go with resources then you will have to re-do all the localization code you have now

Comment: keeping in view the above comment of @VsevolodGoloviznin i'd like to know, if you necessarily need to keep your multi-lingual data in DB? what sort of data is it? is names of labels, errors msgs, etc? or What?

Comment: @Zeeshan: I went with database design because I need my user to be able to add new language without me modyfing the code at all. The data in the database is mostly label and error message, basically every text on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to go with static dictionary in this case, as @Vsevolod-Goloviznin suggested in the comments.
Let me elaborate my approach

1. You probably have a localized resource in your database identified with some named key and language key as well:

   ```
   var homePageTitle = Database.GetResource("homeTitle", "es");
   ```
2. You should build up a static dictionary that will be used as cache and will have all the resources in the database in memory, for easy and convenient access:

   ```
   public static MultiLanguageManager {
       private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> ContentCache;

       ...
       public static GetResource(string key, string language) {
           return (ContentCache[language])[key];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then in your front-end you will have something like this:

   ```
   ...
   <title>@MultiLanguageManager.GetResource("aboutTitle", "en")</title>
   ...
   ```
4. Whenever user changes the localized content in the database, you should rebuild the ContentCache dictionary manually:

   ```
   // update localized content
   ...
   MultiLanguageManager.RebuildContentCache();
   ...
   ```

By using this approach you can reduce the number of database calls to minimum (retrieve only logic units, and not static resources), and control the consistency of your localization data.
One possible drawback might be the size of the static dictionary that you will build, but with Today's abundance of resources, this should not be a problem in 99% of the cases.